# How do I utilize multiple ellipses in a syntax definition?

Tags: racket

```
(define-syntax syntax1
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((syntax2 arg1 arg2 ... param ...)
     (append
      (syntax2 arg1 arg2 ... param)
      ...)
     )
    )
  )

(define-syntax syntax2
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((syntax2 arg1 arg2 ... param)
    ;Body just returns a list
     )
    )
  )
```

I would like to call `syntax2` for however many `param`s there are. The error I get is that the second ellipsis is misplaced. But it follows param, so I am not sure. My logic is that the `(syntax2 arg1 arg2 ... param)` is repeated due to the second set of ellipses, but with `param` replaced by `param2`.

Thank you.

Comment: How could you tell the difference between what should be considered an `arg2` and what should be considered a `param`? For example, in `(syntax1 a b c d)`, how should `b c d` be divided between the `arg2` and `param` patterns?

Comment: I actually considered that, and tried using just a random word in the syntax-rules. `syntax-rules (for)`, then in the pattern I tried `syntax2 arg1 arg2 ... for param ...)`, but it still resulted in the same. Not sure if that is an overall improvement regardless whether it solves the problem.

Comment: `syntax-rules` won't let you do that, but `syntax-parse` might. What are you trying to express here? You said "the `(syntax2 arg1 arg2 ... param)` is repeated due to the second set of ellipses", but I'm not sure exactly what that means to you

Comment: By the way the `for` idea you had does work if you use `syntax-parse`

Comment: I will look into syntax-parse thanks!